# Should I brine a goose?

Tags: brining, goose

I've had really good luck with brining turkey & chicken. I am making goose for this Christmas and have found mixed suggestions on whether to brine the goose. Does the fat content of an average goose lend towards not brining? Are their alternate techniques that would better bring out flavour in a roast goose (just do a straight roast, no brine)?

Comment: Koshering is one technique to consider ( [Source](http://www.foodnetwork.com/good-eats/good-eats-twas-the-night-before-good-eats/index.html) ).  You also might want to consider fairly low and slow for the heat.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. The fat content of goose, like most waterfowl, is very high. This makes it unsuitable for brining. Brining is intended to bring moisture to meats that tend to dry out, such as chicken and turkey.

See [my answer](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/1442/60/#2729) to "[What are the basics of brining meat?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/1442/60)" for more details.

Comment: thanks for that info . Brining a turkey or a goose was completely foreign to me. It was helpful and I think I have a plan new years.

Answer (score 0):

If you have purchased farm-bred goose, the fat content is probably too high.

If you have wild goose, a brine would probably be a great idea.  I usually cook wild goose in a stew, so that the moisture level is high since wild goose are very lean birds.  The closes thing I can compare wild goose to is a very low-fat roast beef type of texture.