# How to ensure that spices reach inside the eggs in the egg curry?

Tags: eggs, curry

For egg curry, I boil the eggs, shell them, pierce them with a fork and deep fry them. 
Then I prepare the gravy and pressure cook the eggs and the gravy.

Anything I do, doesn't let the spices go inside the eggs.
I was thinking of cutting the eggs into halves but then on pressure cooking they'll split up!

Comment: What is egg curry?

Comment: @gunbuster363 Wow, western country people call it something else, maybe: http://www.merirasoi.com/recipedetail/tomato-egg-curry-recipe.aspx?ci=36

Comment: Never heard of it, but that sounds tasty.  I know what I'm making for my next brunch!

Comment: @BobMcGee Generally people here don't fry the eggs before putting them in the curry, I do deep fry, till the skin turns light brown. I don't like eating raw eggs in a curry. Anyway, the question is how to get the spices inside the eggs! Help.

Comment: So, you want to insert spices... into a hard boiled egg... without messing up the skin too much?  Perhaps the question could be edited to make this a bit clearer?

Comment: @BobMcGee I do poke the egg with fork (many times), but that doesn't help, I am ready to mess up with its skin, but if I cut it up totally, the yellow yolk will get lost in the gravy :(

Comment: @BobMcGee Perhaps after silting them up, we can tie them with the cotton strings, as we do in the stuffed vegetables like these: http://tiffinbox.wordpress.com/2010/06/06/bharva-karela/

Comment: To what point do you boil the eggs?  Are they hard boiled prior to being fried?  Or is the yolk still runny?

Comment: @BobMcGee That means I have no other choice than doing whatever you said, yesterday after deep frying the full boiled eggs, I silted half their body, that means they were joint only till their waist, then I put them in the gravy and boiled it for some 10-15 minutes. It still didn't work out. I'll avoid the alcohol though. This thread can't get any better answers than what you posted, though.

Comment: I think you mean "slit the eggs in half" not "silted half their body."

Comment: @BobMcGee I meant that I cut the eggs in half but ensured there were joined at bottom. PS I am NOT a native English speaker.

Comment: @Anisha: I know you're not a native English speaker, and I know what it's like trying to get by in a foreign language.  I'm trying to be helpful with corrections, not trying to be a jerk.

Comment: @BobMcGee I know that you are not being a jerk and I am open to corrections :) and in fact in _LinuxQuestions.org_ we have a thread there for English grammar corrections, I am the top poster there. ;) http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/general-10/problems-with-english-questions-vocabulary-grammar-post-here-654375/page4.html#post4061663

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[I said:](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/15815/how-to-ensure-that-spices-reach-inside-the-eggs-in-the-egg-curry#comment19695_15815)

> I am ready to mess up with its skin, but if I cut it up totally, the yellow yolk will get lost in the gravy.

Yesterday I did an experiment:

After properly **hard boiling** the eggs, I shelled them and **cut them into two parts**  ***vertically***.

I fried these sliced eggs **on both sides** in around **3 (6 ml) spoons oil** in a *semi circle* **wok**. No, the yolk didn't get lost in the oil. It was all intact in the sliced eggs.

I fried all the spices etc. in the **wok**, and added the water as needed. Now, as a final step, I carefully placed the fried sliced eggs in the same *wok* **[with the yolk side facing up]**, covered with a lid, and let it boil on simmer gas for some minutes.

This time the spices **did** get inside the egg yolk, and also the yolk was completely intact.

- Since the eggs are sliced, pressure cooker usage may cause the yolk to dismantle. An open vessel usage is a must in this case.
- It is also necessary to keep the yolk side **facing up** when you place the eggs in the curry for the final boil up to keep them intact.

[Here is how **I** made the egg curry finally.](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/blog/anisha-kaul-445448/egg-curry-with-meat-masala-north-indian-style-34870/)

Answer (score 3):

I have never done egg curry before... but your problem reminded me of [chinese marbled eggs](http://steamykitchen.com/2147-chinese-tea-eggs-recipe.html)

Marbled eggs are soaked for several hours to overnight and soy/tea does not don't get to the yolk, so no wonder that you don't get good penetration of the spices.

Maybe you can think of putting the eggs in a spice concentrate in advance and let them soak before splitting them and letting them cook with the gravy.

Comment: But then you yourself said that soaking them does no good (yolk is not reached)?

Comment: That's why I was thinking of using a spice concentrate. Maybe the colour doesn't reach the inside but the flavour might (esp if you poke them.

Answer (score 2):

I have a notion, but it is an educated guess, and may not be practical to use; however, I think it's also a really cool experiment and potentially an elegant solution.  It's also an alternative to an extremely long (days or more) soak in flavored liquid.

### The Theory

From the [Cooking Issues](http://www.cookingissues.com/) blog, we know that you can infuse flavors into alcohol or water using a [nitrous oxide cream whipper](http://www.cookingissues.com/2010/08/11/infusion-profusion-game-changing-fast-%E2%80%98n-cheap-technique/).  The method is that you put liquid and herbs/seeds/fruits in the whipper, pressurize it with nitrous oxide, then release the pressure suddenly.  The gas pressure forces liquid and gas deep into what you're infusing and then when the pressure is released, the gas and liquid are abruptly pulled, out, bringing flavor with it.  **You should be able to do this in reverse, using gas pressure to force flavored liquid into a peeled, pierced, hard-boiled egg.**  You'll have to use a pressure cooker or cream whipper.

### The practice:

Prepare HEAVILY spice flavored broth, by simmering herbs and spices for several hours to overnight in water.  Maybe add a little alcohol beforehand to help extract flavors. Next, prepare lightly hard boiled eggs, peel them, and pierce them with forks until the tines reach some distance into the yolk.

Place eggs and liquid in either a cream whipper or a pressure cooker. Pressurize the vessel, and swirl or shake to help mix.  Then allow to sit for a minute or two, and release pressure.  If flavor doesn't carry through enough, you might need to allow it to sit for a longer period.

### Potential Improvements:

- Try reducing your flavored liquid beforehand for a more concentrated flavor.
- Try it with increasing portions of alcohol; many flavor compounds are more soluble in water than alcohol.
- Use a warmer liquid (warmer liquids dissolve substances better)
- Allow the pressurized vessel to sit for longer periods (may cause problems if using a pressure cooker, as it might overcook)

Comment: +1 (I was actually about to recommend something similar).  To simplify things, you could also try cooking the gravy in the pressure cooker along with the eggs.

Comment: Nitrous oxide is a pain in the head (literally) if you suffer from migraine. I hate the idea of using it.

Comment: @klypos: Once the pressure is released, only traces of nitrous should remain in the food, and these will evaporate quickly on exposure to air.  Cooking should reduce this amount further.  @Esultanik: If you read the original question & comments carefully, you'll see she already tried pressure cooking in just gravy.

Comment: Bob, yesterday I did an experiment with this dish, and I succeeded.   No offence intended, but I'll have to select my own answer now.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a purely theoretical solution - in the sense that I haven't tried it. If you want to make spices penetrate *meat* instead of eggs, one of the best options is [brining it](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1442/what-are-the-basics-and-options-of-brining-meat-for-example-chicken). The salt makes some of the cell walls collapse, which allows the spices in. This might work with eggs as well.

To try this, make a separate batch of gravy that you oversalt, soak the boiled eggs in it for a day or two, then deep fry and pressure cook. You might want to undersalt the gravy that you pressure cook it in, to compensate for the extra salty eggs.

If you try this, let us know how it goes!

Comment: If they are to be brined before boiling, the process [could take up to one month](http://neckredrecipes.blogspot.com/2009/10/salting-chicken-eggs-with-brine.html).  If they are to be brined after the shells are removed, it probably won't take as long.

Comment: I was thinking of after removing the shells.

Comment: Boiled eggs are often pickled in vinegar - if you do this at home, adding pickling spices will allow the spices to permeate the egg - but that takes months to get through, 3 months minimum after pickling. Pickled eggs DO work well with a curry sauce.